# Angular 7, Creating and running new project fails

Tags: angular, zlib, angular7

I am following all the instructions mentioned on Angular site to install and run new project using Angular 7 but its giving me following errors, I tried many tricks from deleting cache to deleting entire node-modules and npm but nothing works, I need help, Please go through my below errors which i am continuously getting from yesterday.

**Step 1: Successfully Installed Angular 7**

```
C:\Users\me>npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> 
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@7.1.3
updated 1 package in 23.447s
```

**Step 2: Switched folder and created my-app (But it's giving error while creating my-app, see below)**

```
C:\wamp\www>ng new my-app
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE my-app/angular.json (3768 bytes)
CREATE my-app/package.json (1305 bytes)
CREATE my-app/README.md (1022 bytes)
CREATE my-app/tsconfig.json (435 bytes)
CREATE my-app/tslint.json (2824 bytes)
CREATE my-app/.editorconfig (246 bytes)
CREATE my-app/.gitignore (576 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/index.html (292 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/polyfills.ts (3694 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/browserslist (388 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/karma.conf.js (980 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/tsconfig.app.json (166 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/tsconfig.spec.json (256 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.component.html (1120 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (978 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.component.ts (210 bytes)
CREATE my-app/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE my-app/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE my-app/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
CREATE my-app/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (298 bytes)
CREATE my-app/e2e/src/app.po.ts (204 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance 
only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@^0.4.2 
(node_modules\scss-tokenizer\node_modules\source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: zlib: unexpected end of file

npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12- 
14T04_43_19_244Z-debug.log

Package install failed, see above.
```

**Step 3: Then I switched to my-app**

```
C:\wamp\www>cd my-app
```

**Step 4: Started the server but here too it's breaking**

```
C:\wamp\www\my-app>ng serve --open
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from 
"C:\\wamp\\www\\my-app".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from 
"C:\\wamp\\www\\my-app".
at Object.resolve (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules 
\@angular\cli\node_modules\ @angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] 
(C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules 
\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\ 
architect.js:132:40)
at Observable._trySubscribe 
(C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules 
\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\ Observable.js:44:25)
at Observable.subscribe 
(C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules 
\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
at 
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules 
\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:99:19
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Observable.toPromise 
(C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules 
\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:97:16)
at ServeCommand.initialize 
(C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules 
\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:88:94)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:43:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:779:11)

C:\wamp\www\my-app>
```

Please suggest me something what I can do here, Thanks

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to mention that if the package failed to install, it'll surely fail compiling. Are you creating the Angular project in an command prompt running as administrator? You're in a folder directly in the C: directory so that might be the issue?

Comment: I assume you checked the log (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12- 14T04_43_19_244Z-debug.log)? That may contain more specifics as to why the "ng create" failed. That would most likely need to be resolved before expecting the "ng serve" (which builds and serves the app) to complete successfully.

Comment: Hello @Keithers, Thanks for the reply, Yes I am running node command prompt as an administrator. My laptop has only one drive "C:" and I keep all the stuff in that.

Comment: Did you make sure to run `npm install` in the project folder? What is your Node and npm version? You can get it by running `node -v` and `npm -v`

Comment: Hello @Keithers, Yes I tried running `npm install` too in that folder but that too didn't work, I have "npm version 6.5.0" and "node version v11.4.0" running on my system.

Comment: I think you had already installed the angulat-cli and updated now?

Comment: @secretsuperstar, No, I installed it yesterday only. I have fresh/latest setup of node and angular on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution finally!

I just cleared the cache by running the following command and ran `npm install` again and it worked.

```
>npm cache clean --force
>npm install
```

So if it happens with anyone, Please follow the below steps:

```
>npm install -g @angular/cli
>ng new my-app
>cd my-app
>npm cache clean --force
>npm install
>ng serve --open
```

And you are good to go!
Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Ah, this would have been the next suggestion haha. I'm glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue yesterday, How did I resolved that..

1.Uninstall the current angular cli. **npm uninstall @angular/cli**

2.Delete the folder : [image]

3.Delete the temp file of node_module if any exist, using **%AppData%\npm-cache** in cmd.

4.Restart the system.

5.Give fresh install with  npm install @angular/cli@  eg: 6.0.2

6. Done your are good to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

> delete the node_modules:

rm -rf node_modules
 and deleted the package-lock.json,

> then re-install:
>     npm install 
>     It works for me.

Comment: I feel there is problem with zlib. node-modules is not getting created in my folder even after running `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

1. uninstall npm
2. install angular cli

https://stackasian.com/angular/create-new